# Comparing Cell Phone Plans in C++

Tags: c++

I'm in Intro to C++. My assignment is to write a program that will act like an employee terminal. The program should prompt the customer for which plan they are on (A,B, or C) the program should recognize both upper and lower case letters. Then prompt them for their data usage. Plan A is 15 dollars and comes with 200mb of data with a overage charge of 0.06 per additional mb. Plan B is 25 dollars and comes with 2000mb of data, 0.02 per additional mb. Plan C is unlimited.

I've already worked all of that out. The part I'm stuck on is the comparison. If a person in on plan A and lets say they use more than 367mb ($25.02) but less than 784mb ($50.04) It has to tell them how much they would have saved if they switched to plan B. If they use more than 367mb it has to tell them how much they would have saved on plan C. I also have to do they same for people that are on plan B who go over there date but only if their overage totals more than the price of plan C and therefore would have saved money it they were on plan C.

The program does not need to advise on downgrading plans (i.e. move from plan C to A) only upgrades.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* Project One
 Wriitten by A-R
*/
int main ()
{  

    char    Plan_omega;
    int     MB;
    double  Plan_Cost_A, Plan_Cost_B, Plan_Cost_C, Variation_A;

    cout << "Which plan does the customer currently have?"<< endl;                           // Input of the customer's current plan.
    cin  >>  Plan_omega;

    while ( !(Plan_omega=='A') && !(Plan_omega=='B') && !(Plan_omega=='C') &&   // Must input either A, B, or C (upper of lower case) or it will reprompt.
            !(Plan_omega=='a') && !(Plan_omega=='b') && !(Plan_omega=='c') ) {

        cout << "Please enter only A, B, or C" << endl;
        cin  >>  Plan_omega; 
    }

    cout << "How many MB did the customer use last month?" <<endl;  
    cin  >> MB;

    while ( MB < 0 || MB > 10000) {

        cout << "Please enter a value between 0 and 10,000" << endl;
        cin  >>  MB; 
    }

    switch (Plan_omega){
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
        cout << "The customer's total bill is $"; 
            if (MB > 200) {
                Plan_Cost_A = 15 + ((MB - 200) * 0.06);
            } else {
                Plan_Cost_A = 15;
            }
            cout << Plan_Cost_A <<endl;
            break;

        case 'B':
        case 'b':
        cout << "The customer's total bill is $";     
            if (MB > 2000){
                Plan_Cost_B = 25 + ((MB - 2000) * 0.02);
            } else {
                Plan_Cost_B = 25;
            }
            cout << Plan_Cost_B <<endl;
            break;
        cout << "The customer's total bill is $";    

        case 'C':
        case 'c':
        cout << "The customer's total bill is $";     
            if (MB > -1){
                Plan_Cost_C = 50;
            } else {
                Plan_Cost_C = 50;
            cout << Plan_Cost_C <<endl;
            }
            break;




    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Thank you for your assistance. I wrote a much shorter form of the question last time and everybody asked for more info. I was trying to keep it short and I failed.

Also, I know there are a number of ways to make this program smaller or add shortcuts. My teacher specifically asked that the program be made in a similar manner to what mine looks like, thanks again.

Comment: Always calculate `Plan_Cost_A`, `Plan_Cost_B`, and `Plan_Cost_C`. Then use the `switch` to decide wich one to output as the customer's bill. Then you can compare the calculated costs for A, B, and C to check which is the best match for the customer.

Comment: Calculate all the prices, and only show the prices that are below the user's current plan price. What's the problem? In poorly thought-out assignments like this, the teacher is usually looking for some specific use of recently learned code, so look over your notes and don't over think it. **K**eep  **I**t **S**imple, **S**tupid

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an `if...elseif` block to compare the value of `MB` to 367 and 748 and use that to determine if you should show the comparisons to the other plans.

Example:

```
int main (void)
{    
    char Plan_omega;
    int MB;
    //get the value of Plan_omega and MB
    //Calculate Plan_Cost_A, Plan_Cost_B, and Plan_Cost_C

    switch (Plan_omega){
        //code here to display their current bill
    }

    if (MB > 367 && MB < 748) {
        // Calculate what they would have saved on Plan B
    }
    elseif (MB > 367) {
        // Calculate what they would have saved on Plan C
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

I don't feel this question falls within the realm of questions you can ask on Stack Overflow, however and I predict it will be marked as Off-Topic soon.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I previously tried the if, else if statement along with the (MB > 367....) almost exactly as your wrote it. The program ignored the MB parameters though.

Comment: What do you mean it ignored the MB parameters?

Comment: It would run the calculations even if the MB were below or above what I set. I coded it exactly as you suggested it. I did it last night and I was quite tired so let me try it again.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage this approach, because it implies hard-coding the thresholds (367 and 748). Should the rates ever change, you'd have to modify the code that calculates the monthly cost (that is ok), AND this piece of code (not ok). And by the way, the thresholds have been calculated manually, by solving an equation. This is not the right approach. The OP already has the 3 costs, he should stick to them. Reason on costs directly. This way, however the rates can change, this part of the program will always be correct.

Comment: @FabioTurati What you have said is correct, but his original question mentioned these MB thresholds so I included them in my answer. For that matter, even the rates are hard-coded in so your point is moot unless you want to ask him to modify his program to ask for the rates as well.