# Can I get any suggestions on how to fix this C++ program on calculating data plans?

Tags: c++, logic

I am a coding newbie who is perplexed and confused about how to make this program work.

Display a menu to show the different data plans. Plan 1 is $39.99 per month with 450 included minutes. Additional minutes are $0.45 per minute. Plan 2 is $59.99 per month with 900 provided minutes. Additional minutes are $0.40 per minute. Plan 3 is $69.99 per month with unlimited minutes.

• The customer’s account number 
  • The customer’s plan number • The
    total minutes used by the customer 
  • The total amount due (formatted)

Input validation: be sure the user only selects package 1, 2 or 3.

I searched stackoverflow with three different search query variations: 'data plans', 'cell phone data plans', 'how to calculate data plans' and I did find this post [Comparing Cell Phone Plans in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908631/comparing-cell-phone-plans-in-c) and it was a somewhat similar program but not similar enough. I googled it also and found some similar programs but they were more helpful, but too complex and didn't help me enough.

I am at a standstill and don't know how to calculate the total bill using the number of minutes used on Plan One and Plan Two that are over the allotted minutes with both of those plans.

Here's what I have so far:

```
int main()
{
    // Declare and initialize double constant variables
    const double planOne = 39.99,
                 planTwo = 59.99,
                 planThree = 69.99,
                 planOneExtMins = 0.45,
                 planTwoExtMins = 0.40;

    // Declare integer variables
    int planThreeUnlMins,
        custPlanNum,
        numMinsUsed;

    // Declare double variables
    double billOne,
           billTwo,
           billThree;

    // Declare unsigned variable
    unsigned int planChoice;

    // Initialize string variable
    string custAcctNum;

    // Ask for customer account number
    cout << "\n\nPlease enter your customer account number in all capital 
    letters and numbers and then press enter when done: ";
    cin >> custAcctNum;

    // Welcome statement
    cout << "Welcome to the Python Services Mobile Provider program that 
    will help you determine your monthly bill\n\n";

    // Display menu with the different data plans offered
    cout << "Data Plans Menu";
    cout << "\n\n\t1. Plan One is $39.99 per month with 450 included 
    minutes. Additional minutes are 0.45 per minute.";
    cout << "\n\t2. Plan Two is $59.99 per month with 900 provided minutes. 
    Additional minutes are $0.40 per minute.";
    cout << "\n\t3. Plan Three is $69.99 per month with unlimited minutes." 
    << endl;
    cout << "Please enter your choice of a data plan: ";

    // Validate if the choice of the user is a number between one and four
    int planChoice = 0;
    cin >> planChoice;

    if(!( planChoice == 3 )) {
            // Display restart program statement and end program
            cout << "Please restart the program and enter a number between 
            one and four" << endl;
            cout << "Program ending";
            return 0;
            }

    // Ask user for the number of minutes used
    cout << "\n\nPlease enter the number of minutes used: ";
    cin >> numMinsUsed;

    if( planChoice == 1 ) {
    // What code can I use to use the number of minutes used to  
    calculate the total cost of a particular data plan?
    }

    // Set the numeric output formatting
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    switch (planChoice) {

    case 1: cout << "Please enter the amount of minutes used: " << endl;
    cin >> numMinsUsed;
    break;

    case 2: cout << "Please enter the amount of minutes used: " << endl;
    cin >> numMinsUsed;
    break;

    case 3: cout << "Please enter the amount of minutes used: " << endl;
    break;

    default: cout << "Please enter a valid plan number from above" << endl;
    cin >> numMinsUsed;

    }

    if( planChoice == 1 ) {
        billOne = planOne + ( .45 * numMinsUsed );
    }
    else if( planChoice == 2 ) {
        billTwo = planTwo + ( .40 * numMinsUsed );
    }

    else if (planChoice == 3 )  {
        billThree = planThree;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an improvement to your question, I suggest you get rid of all the unrelated stuff (code and text). Since you are only asking how to calculate something, focus only on that. Have some test inputs, and what you expect their values to be and the values you're getting.

Comment: Your code has other issues, like 1 and 2 will never work as initial input, but let's ignore that and do some math. Plan 1, 1000 minutes used. $39.99 + (1000-450) * 0.45 = ?  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Tas Thank you for your suggestion. I tried to get rid of most of the unrelated code and text. I will have to try to test the inputs also.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It does make sense. I just don't know how to translate that into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you might calculate the cost of each plan based on the minutes used.

I used 0 minutes included at a cost of 0 per minute to represent unlimited minutes because it makes the math easy, and use a function to return the display value for those minutes so 0 = "unlimited".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

double calculateCost(double planCost, 
    double minuteCost, 
    int minutesIncluded, 
    int minutesUsed)
{
    double cost = planCost;
    int overage = minutesUsed - minutesIncluded;
    if (overage > 0)
    {
        cost += minuteCost * overage;
    }
    return cost;
}

std::string includedMinutesString(int numMinutes)
{
    if (numMinutes > 0)
    {
        return std::to_string(numMinutes);
    }
    return "unlimited";
}

int main()
{
    {
        double planCost = 39.99;
        double minuteCost = 0.45;
        int minutesIncluded = 450;
        int minutesUsed = 1000;
        std::cout << "Plan Cost: " << planCost << " with " << 
            includedMinutesString(minutesIncluded) << " minutes included\n";
        std::cout << "Cost with " << minutesUsed << " minutes used is  " << 
            calculateCost(planCost, minuteCost, minutesIncluded, minutesUsed) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    {
        double planCost = 59.99;
        double minuteCost = 0.40;
        int minutesIncluded = 900;
        int minutesUsed = 1000;
        std::cout << "Plan Cost: " << planCost << " with " << 
            includedMinutesString(minutesIncluded) << " minutes included\n";
        std::cout << "Cost with " << minutesUsed << " minutes used is  " << 
            calculateCost(planCost, minuteCost, minutesIncluded, minutesUsed) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    {
        double planCost = 69.99;
        double minuteCost = 0;
        int minutesIncluded = 0;
        int minutesUsed = 1000;
        std::cout << "Plan Cost: " << planCost << " with " << 
            includedMinutesString(minutesIncluded) << " minutes included\n";
        std::cout << "Cost with " << minutesUsed << " minutes used is  " << 
            calculateCost(planCost, minuteCost, minutesIncluded, minutesUsed) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```